# LD_PRELOAD free/malloc/realloc/calloc free doesn't work

Tags: c, malloc, free, glibc, ld-preload

I'm recoding malloc/calloc/realloc/free functions.
For now, I finished malloc and for tests, I just write "free" function like :

```
void free(void* ptr) {}
```

And I test my functions with different software, works with ls/firefox/man ...

But, with software like GIMP I have :

```
*** Error in `gimp': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0000000001d75e00 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80996)[0x7f280d77e996]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x82614)[0x7f280d780614]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_memalign+0x9a)[0x7f280d781e1a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(posix_memalign+0x4c)[0x7f280d783a2c]
```

SO, I don't understand why I've this problem with a free which do nothing.
(my free function is called, I tested with a "printf")

Does someone know where it comes from?

Thanks for reading
Hope to hear you

Comment: in which context you use the free ? a bit more code of where it fits in willl nice.

Comment: I didn't use the free, it's why this error looks weird.
In this message the error comes from posix_memalign, I recode it like : 
    int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size) {

}
And the error has changed, now it's : ***MEMORY-ERROR***: [10180]: GSlice: failed to allocate 1008 bytes (alignment: 1024): Key has been revoked

Comment: It seems like the original system free got called from somewhere, perhaps from inside a library.

Comment: The problem occured only when the software is built with GTK (like gimp/ chromium), is it possible that GTK call free?